# Repair my partitions and reinstall Grub2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I messed up my partitions because I wanted to increase my Ubuntu disk space (I had a boot partition between the two partitions I wanted to merge, so tried to delete merge partitions and re-install grub2) I used gparted.

But I am not able to re-install grub2 facing errors

```
GRUB failed to install to the following devices: /dev/nvme0n1
```

I have/had dual-boot configuration with a partition for windows and Ubuntu (I took some space from Windows partition to increase Ubuntu partition)

```
➜  ~ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ACF0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  500GB  500GB               Basic data partition  msftdata


Model: PC300 NVMe SK hynix 256GB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags
```

I tried to purge/reinstall grub:

sudo apt-get purge grub grub-pc grub-common
sudo apt-get install grub-common grub-pc

[image: Tried to run Boot Repair]

The problem is that GParted don't see any partition anymore :-/ so how can I create my bios-boot partition without damaging the other partitions ?

[image]

Disks how a little better view lol but my windows partition is detected as free space...

[image]

Thanks

Comment: When you said you deleted the Boot partition did you delete /boot partition which most desktops do not have, or the ESP - efi system partition which is required for UEFI boot. With gpt partitioning you have to either have the ESP (FAT32) or bios_grub partition (unformatted) for grub to install. Did you leave Windows fast start up on? Then Linux NTFS driver cannot see the NTFS partition(s). http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu If you left fast start up on, you may need to use your Windows repair disk first.

Comment: Gparted works fine. You're looking at the wrong partition. If you click on the up-down arrow in the top right corner you should see the 32 GB partition. It looks like that you removed the EFS boot partition. First make a new 150MB **FAT32** partition, then boot into Live Ubuntu and perform a [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: @oldfred this what I shouldn't have done unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401002/… (the deleted partition was grub2 core.img).

Comment: @PaulBenson I don't see it unfortunately with Gparted, wouldn't a boot-repair in my installed Ubuntu do the same job ?

Comment: @PaulBenson how could I create a new partition with my Ubuntu not seeing the allocated space (windows partition...) ?

Comment: First edit question. Delete the `blkid` output and the `purge grub` image stuff. Start Terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and run `sudo parted -l`. Post up output from that.

Comment: Boot-Repair does not create partitions, it assumes you have correct partition for version you are using, or an ESP for UEFI or bios_grub for BIOS boot mode. And if Windows issues, you must fix those first and cannot do that from Ubuntu.

Comment: `parted -l` confirms that it sees 2 disks including your NVMe drive but only 1 incomplete partition NVMe1, no size or file system shown. So I have to assume no Ubuntu exists on that drive any more. So you'll need to reinstall from live Ubuntu.  From there first try gparted again and make one primary partition of 60 GB size in ext4 for 'root', then do the reinstall.

Comment: hmm @PaulBenson I am on the installed Ubuntu right now (I am not in a live CD), not sure really what that means

Comment: Live Ubuntu (LU) refers to the installation files on a **pen/flash drive**. I did not mention a CD. From there you can run Ubuntu on a trial basis or do an install to an HDD/SSD. You should already have LU. It comes with gparted already installed. So make an ext4 primary partition on your NVMe drive **from LU** and install Ubuntu onto that. Don't worry about boot partitions. It will make its own during installation.

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid using `apt purge` or `apt remove` on packages involving GRUB since it can leave your system in an unbootable state. Instead, there are two commands that exist to resolve these kinds of problems:

- `sudo update-grub` takes an already installed GRUB and updates it's configuration so that it can find bootable partitions and put them into menu, create separate menu entries for all the available kernels, etc.
- `grub-install some_disk` will install GRUB into the provided disk and update the Master Boot Record (MBR) of the system.

To further complicate things Windows has a very nasty habit of not actually shutting down, but instead *hibernating*. This causes serious problems because you shut windows down, go into Ubuntu or some other operating system, make changes to the disk, then go back into Windows. However, since you never actually "shutdown" Windows it stayed in memory and when shutting down clobbered the disk overwriting the changes you've made to the partition layout.

I have also seen a bug with GParted where some changes made to the disk while the system was booted weren't reflected in GParted until after restarting.

My suggestion is use the [System Rescue CD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/Download/) to resolve the problem. In specific it contains [Test Disk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) which can help recover deleted partitions, which is effectively what has likely happened.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried testdisk but it didn't see my disk (/dev/nvm0n1 it sees only /dev/sda).
I also tried update-grub and grub-install which failed with the same error message: grub-install: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/nvme0n1p6.  Check your device.map.